# How can i set default file selected in HTML INPUT FILE ELEMENT?

Tags: jquery, html, file-io

When my page load. I want input file element has some default value. eg. Default file selected automatically when page load.

How can i do this?

Comment: NO, not possible yet

Comment: Not possible for obvious security reasons

Comment: Blatantly typing your answer in google return [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25405364/1997232) answer. Try to type question in google first next time maybe?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Putting default value in <input type=file....>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323010/putting-default-value-in-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. If you could, you'd be able to steal files from a user's computer (because you can, after all, programmatically and automatically submit forms).

Comment: Yes, You are right. Can i set selected value to another file input object, using jquery?

Comment: No, for the same reason.