# how to set a fix source to file upload control from which it will get documents?

Tags: javascript, jquery

here I want to set the fix source location to file uploader from which only an user can choose file(s).
my html for file uploader is like

```
Selecte Document  <input type="file" id="myFile"/>
```

i.e is allowing me to choose documents from any location.

Comment: You can't do that. Please refer to : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323010/putting-default-value-in-input-type-file

Comment: why i can't do this?i saw the link you shared but that is not clear to me ,to convice my self as this  i can't do

Comment: It is more like - You should not do that for security reasons.  I would not want anybody to just access any file from my computer without my intervention. If you populate the value like - value='c:\sometext.txt' , it would be uploaded along the form.

Comment: no actualy what am trying to say that,i dont want to set any value to that control i wanted to open one of default location means when user will click choose file then that specific location will be opened,and there will be multiple documents so user can select any file from that location(i.e any file from that location)

Comment: From some folder on your site only?  Then let user select one of the files that already are there. No need to use file tag only.

Comment: No need to use file tag only.means?